# How does HashSet compare elements for equality?

Tags: c#, hashset

I have a class that is `IComparable`:

```
public class a : IComparable
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public a(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        return this.Id.CompareTo(((a)obj).Id);
    }
}
```

When I add a list of object of this class to a hash set:

```
a a1 = new a(1);
a a2 = new a(2);
HashSet<a> ha = new HashSet<a>();
ha.add(a1);
ha.add(a2);
ha.add(a1);
```

Everything is fine and `ha.count` is `2`, but:

```
a a1 = new a(1);
a a2 = new a(2);
HashSet<a> ha = new HashSet<a>();
ha.add(a1);
ha.add(a2);
ha.add(new a(1));
```

Now `ha.count` is `3`.

1. Why doesn't `HashSet` respect `a`'s `CompareTo` method.
2. Is `HashSet` the best way to have a list of unique objects?

Comment: Add an implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` in the constructor or implement it in the class `a`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb301504(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 189, accepted):

It uses an [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) ([`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) unless you specify a different one on construction).

When you add an element to the set, it will find the hash code using `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode`, and store both the hash code and the element (after checking whether the element is already in the set, of course).

To look an element up, it will first use the `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode` to find the hash code, then for all elements with the same hash code, it will use `IEqualityComparer<T>.Equals` to compare for actual equality.

That means you have two options:

- Pass a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` into the constructor. This is the best option if you can't modify the `T` itself, or if you want a non-default equality relation (e.g. "all users with a negative user ID are considered equal"). This is almost never implemented on the type itself (i.e. `Foo` doesn't implement `IEqualityComparer<Foo>`) but in a separate type which is only used for comparisons.
- Implement equality in the type itself, by overriding `GetHashCode` and `Equals(object)`. Ideally, implement `IEquatable<T>` in the type as well, particularly if it's a value type. These methods will be called by the default equality comparer.

Note how none of this is in terms of an *ordered* comparison - which makes sense, as there are certainly situations where you can easily specify equality but not a total ordering. This is all the same as `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, basically.

If you want a set which uses *ordering* instead of just equality comparisons, you should use [`SortedSet<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd412070.aspx) from .NET 4 - which allows you to specify an `IComparer<T>` instead of an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. This will use `IComparer<T>.Compare` - which will delegate to `IComparable<T>.CompareTo` or `IComparable.CompareTo` if you're using `Comparer<T>.Default`.

Comment: +1 Also note @tyriker's answer (that IMO should be a comment here) which points out that the simplest way to leverage said `IEqualityComparer<T>.GetHashCode/Equals()` is to implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` on `T` itself (and while you're doing that, you'd also implement the strongly typed counterpart:- `bool IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)` )

Comment: Although very accurate this answer may be somewhat confusing, especially for new users as it doesn't clearly state that for the simplest case overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` is enough - as mentioned in @tyriker's answer.

Comment: Imo once you implement `IComparable` (or `IComparer` for that matter) you shouldn't be asked to implement equality separately (but just `GetHashCode`). In a sense the comparability interfaces should inherit from equality interfaces. I do understand the performance benefits in having two separate functions (where you can optimize equality separately just by saying if something is equal or not) but still.. Very confusing otherwise when you have specified when the instances are equal in `CompareTo` function and framework wont consider that.

Comment: @nawfal not everything has a logical order. if you're comparing two things that contain a bool property it is just plain awful to have to write something like `a.boolProp == b.boolProp ? 1 : 0` or should it be `a.boolProp == b.boolProp ? 0 : -1` or `a.boolProp == b.boolProp ? 1 : -1`. Yuk!

Comment: @Simon_Weaver it is. I do want to somehow avoid it in my hypothetical feature I was proposing.

Comment: @JonSkeet congrats on just hitting the 1 million rep.  Why does your answer not work but @tyriker's does - ie. don't implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`?  I found with `IEqualityComparer<T>` that `Equals(T a, T b)` was never called.  But the overriden version is.

Comment: @HankCa: Well are you actually passing the comparer into the constructor? It should work fine. I wouldn't have posted it if it didn't work.

Comment: @HankCa: I'm clarifying the answer to make that clearer though.

Comment: Ahh yes, thanks @JonSkeet.  Its been a while since I've done this in Java (and I'm new to C#).  What I was thinking of was Java's comparable where you implement a `int compareTo(T t)` and thinking C#'s `IComparable` was the same.  `IComparable` is infact, just like Java's `Comparator` that like you said, is passed as an argument to the HashSet.

Comment: To extend @Tyriker s "Instead of", you could have `public class a : IEqualityComparer<a> {`, and then `new HashSet<a>(a)`

Comment: @HankCa: No, you'd almost never implement IEqualityComparer for the same class as is implementing it. You'd implement IEquatable instead. Also you don't pass a Comparator to a Java HashSet, for the same reasons... You'd pass one to a TreeSet instead, as that's ordered.

Comment: @HankCa: Comparator doesn't have compareTo, it has compare - it's important to distinguish between "I can compare two values" and "I can compare another value to myself"

Comment: From [your comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality/15413983#comment84109697_8952026) it seems like it's required to pass the `IEqualityComparer` to the HashSet's constructor (I assume that that's what you meant, and not the Type's ctor). Why would that be needed? Wouldn't the HashSet call the `IEqualityComparer` anyway if the Type implements it?

Comment: @ispiro: Which type? The element type? A type normally doesn't implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` of itself, but of a *different* type. That's the difference between `IEqualityComparer<T>` and `IEquatable<T>`. The default comparer will use an `IEquatable<T>` implementation, but the point is to be able to specify a different comparer if you want to.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks. So implementing `IEquatable` and overriding `Equals` and `GetHashCode` _will_ be enough without needing to pass an `IEqualityComparer` to the HashSet. Got it. Thanks again.

Comment: @ispiro: For a type that you control, if you only want one type of equality comparison, yes. (Note that this is covered by the second bullet point in the answer.)

Answer (score 98):

Here's clarification on a part of the answer that's been left unsaid: The object type of your `HashSet<T>` doesn't have to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` but instead just has to override `Object.GetHashCode()` and `Object.Equals(Object obj)`.

Instead of this:

```
public class a : IEqualityComparer<a>
{
  public int GetHashCode(a obj) { /* Implementation */ }
  public bool Equals(a obj1, a obj2) { /* Implementation */ }
}
```

You do this:

```
public class a
{
  public override int GetHashCode() { /* Implementation */ }
  public override bool Equals(object obj) { /* Implementation */ }
}
```

It is subtle, but this tripped me up for the better part of a day trying to get HashSet to function the way it is intended. And like others have said, `HashSet<a>` will end up calling `a.GetHashCode()` and `a.Equals(obj)` as necessary when working with the set.

Comment: Good point. BTW as mentioned on my comment on @JonSkeet's answer, you should also implement `bool IEquatable<T>.Equals(T other)` for a slight efficiency gain but more importantly the clarity benefit. For obv reasons, in addition to the need to implement `GetHashCode` alongside `IEquatable<T>`, the doc for IEquatable<T> mentions that for consistency purposes you should also override the `object.Equals` for consistency

Comment: I tried implementing this. The `ovveride getHashcode` works, but `override bool equals` gets the error: no method found to override. any idea?

Comment: Finally the info i was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: From my comments on above answer - In your "Instead of" case, you could have `public class a : IEqualityComparer<a> {`, and then `new HashSet<a>(a)`.

Comment: But see Jon Skeets comments above.

Comment: Be careful! This will only work with the default `System.Collections.Generic.GenericEqualityComparer<T>`. If your `HashSet` is materialized by Entity Framework, it will have `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer`.

Comment: So is `IEqualityComparer` used by the dictionary or does override work for dictionary too ?

Comment: @WDUK `IEqualityComparer` is used by dictionary, which doesn't inherently depend on `Object.Equals` by default, so override alone won't work. [source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.iequalitycomparer-1?view=net-6.0#remarks)

Comment: You do understand that IEqualityComparer is not to be implemented by the object but actually is a separate class right? If the user can access the object code, then the interface to implement is IEquatable<>.

Answer (score 16):

`HashSet` uses `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.

`CompareTo()` is for ordered sets.

If you want unique objects, but you don't care about their iteration order, `HashSet<T>` is typically the best choice.

Answer (score 7):

`HashSet<T>` constructor receive object what implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for adding new object. If you want to use method in `HashSet` you need to overrride `Equals()` and `GetHashCode()`.

```
namespace HashSet
{
    public class Employe
    {
        public Employe() {
        }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()  {
            return Name;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            return this.Name.Equals(((Employe)obj).Name);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode() {
            return this.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class EmployeComparer : IEqualityComparer<Employe>
    {
        public bool Equals(Employe x, Employe y)
        {
            return x.Name.Trim().ToLower().Equals(y.Name.Trim().ToLower());
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Employe obj)
        {
            return obj.Name.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            HashSet<Employe> hashSet = new HashSet<Employe>(new EmployeComparer());
            hashSet.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Nik" });
            hashSet.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Rob" });
            hashSet.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Joe" });
            Display(hashSet);
            hashSet.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Rob" });
            Display(hashSet);

            HashSet<Employe> hashSetB = new HashSet<Employe>(new EmployeComparer());
            hashSetB.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Max" });
            hashSetB.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Solomon" });
            hashSetB.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Werter" });
            hashSetB.Add(new Employe() { Name = "Rob" });
            Display(hashSetB);

            var union = hashSet.Union<Employe>(hashSetB).ToList();
            Display(union);
            var inter = hashSet.Intersect<Employe>(hashSetB).ToList();
            Display(inter);
            var except = hashSet.Except<Employe>(hashSetB).ToList();
            Display(except);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        static void Display(HashSet<Employe> hashSet)
        {
            if (hashSet.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.Write("Collection is Empty");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var item in hashSet)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, ", item);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }

        static void Display(List<Employe> list)
        {
            if (list.Count == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Collection is Empty");
                return;
            }
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}, ", item);
            }
            Console.Write("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if the Name is null? what's the hash value of null?

Answer (score 7):

I came here looking for answers, but found that all the answers had too much info or not enough, so here is my answer...

Since you've created a custom class you need to implement `GetHashCode` and `Equals`. In this example I will use a class `Student` instead of `a` because it's easier to follow and doesn't violate any naming conventions. **Here is what the implementations look like**:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj)
{
    return obj is Student student && Id == student.Id;
}

public override int GetHashCode()
{
    return HashCode.Combine(Id);
}
```

I stumbled across [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/generate-equals-gethashcode-methods?view=vs-2019) that gives an incredibly easy way to implement these if you're using Visual Studio. In case it's helpful to anyone else, here are complete steps for using a custom data type in a HashSet using Visual Studio:

Given a class `Student` with 2 simple properties and an initializer

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public Student(int id)
    {
        this.Id = id;
    }
 }
```

To Implement IComparable, add `: IComparable<Student>` like so:

```
public class Student : IComparable<Student>
```

You will see a red squiggly appear with an error message saying your class doesn't implement IComparable. Click on suggestions or press Alt+Enter and use the suggestion to implement it.

[image: use the suggestion to implement IComparable]

You will see the method generated. You can then write your own implementation like below:

```
public int CompareTo(Student student)
{
    return this.Id.CompareTo(student.Id);
}
```

In the above implementation only the Id property is compared, name is ignored. Next right-click in your code and select *Quick actions and refactorings*, then *Generate Equals and GetHashCode*

[image: Generate Equals and GetHashCode]

A window will pop up where you can select which properties to use for hashing and even implement IEquitable if you'd like:

[image: pop up where you can select which properties to use for hashing]

Here is the generated code:

```
public class Student : IComparable<Student>, IEquatable<Student> {
    ...
    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Student);
    }

    public bool Equals(Student other)
    {
        return other != null && Id == other.Id;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return HashCode.Combine(Id);
    }
}
```

Now if you try to add a duplicate item like shown below it will be skipped:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Student s1 = new Student(1);
    Student s2 = new Student(2);
    HashSet<Student> hs = new HashSet<Student>();

    hs.Add(s1);
    hs.Add(s2);
    hs.Add(new Student(1)); //will be skipped
    hs.Add(new Student(3));
}
```

You can now use `.Contains` like so:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
{
    if (hs.Contains(new Student(i)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Set contains student with Id {i}");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine($@"Set does NOT contain a student with Id {i}");
    }
}
```

Output:

[image: Console output]

Comment: Fantastic thank you. I was struggling a bit with the other answers and then as you point out, it's built into Visual Studio anyway