# c# Class as key in HashSet

Tags: c#, class, key, hashset

I am using a `HashSet` where I use instances of classes as keys, that is, the references to them.
What I am unsure of, is if the `HashSet` will compare the references, which would mean every instance would be different, or the actual values contained in the object, which is what I need.

Does a `HashSet` compare by value or reference, and if it is the latter, what would be a good way to let it compare by value?

Comment: This link can help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality You'll be able to redefine how comparison is done if it doesn't suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that one.