# POCO comparer not working

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, poco, iequalitycomparer

I have some code that allows me to compare to Entity Framework entities.

However, I've noticed that it sometimes returns false (not matched) when it is in fact true (from a logical perspective).

It fails because of the HashSets - they always return false when compared. HashSets are typically navigation links to other entities which I don't need to compare.

Are there any modifications I can make to this code to make it work correctly?

```
namespace Common.Helper
{
    public sealed class PocoHelper<TPOCO> : IEqualityComparer<TPOCO> where TPOCO : class
    {
        public bool Equals(TPOCO poco1, TPOCO poco2)
        {
            var t = typeof(TPOCO);

            if (poco1.IsNotNull() && poco2.IsNotNull())
            {
                bool areSame = true;

                foreach(var property in typeof(TPOCO).GetPublicProperties())
                {
                    object v1 = property.GetValue(poco1, null);
                    object v2 = property.GetValue(poco2, null);

                    if (!object.Equals(v1, v2))
                    {
                        areSame = false;
                        break;
                    }
                };

                return areSame;
            }

            return poco1 == poco2;
        }   

        public int GetHashCode(TPOCO poco)
        {
            int hash = 0;
            foreach(var property in typeof(TPOCO).GetPublicProperties())
            {
                object val = property.GetValue(poco, null);
                hash += (val == null ? 0 : val.GetHashCode());
            };
            return hash;
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: You have to use IEqualityComparer

Comment: So you must find a way to exclude the HashSets from the comparison. That shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: @IamStalker - would you care to elaborate?

Comment: @GertArnold - do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

You should return false when any or both of the objects you are comparing is null.

```
        if (poco1.IsNotNull() && poco2.IsNotNull())
        {
            bool areSame = true;

            foreach(var property in typeof(TPOCO).GetPublicProperties())
            {
                object v1 = property.GetValue(poco1, null);
                object v2 = property.GetValue(poco2, null);

                if (!object.Equals(v1, v2))
                {
                    areSame = false;
                    break;
                }
            };

            return areSame;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

Because as given on msdn your "==" would return true

```
    // Returns true.
    Console.WriteLine("null == null is {0}", null == null);
```

You can view at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/edakx9da.aspx

Regarding hashsets:
The object type of your HashSet doesn't have to implement IEqualityComparer but instead just has to override Object.GetHashCode() and Object.Equals(Object obj). You can see full post at [How does HashSet compare elements for equality?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality)