# Custom class inside HashSet<>

Tags: c#, hashset

I would like to use `HashSet<>` in order to store large quantities (50-100) of a certain custom class, lets call it "Poster." As far as I know there is some performance benefit in using `HashSet<>` for large number of items over `List<>`. But in order to take advantage of this performance gain, do I "need" to define both of these?

- `public bool Equals(Poster a, Poster b)`
- `public int GetHashCode(Poster obj)`

UPDATE: For anyone looking on how to implement these, this is how I've done it:

```
public bool Equals(PosterImage a, PosterImage b)
{
    return (a.ApiId == b.ApiId);
}

public int GetHashCode(PosterImage obj)
{
    return ((PosterImage) obj).ApiId.GetHashCode();
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How does HashSet compare elements for equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality)

Comment: What kind of performance benefit are you hoping to get? Checking for the existance of an item in a hash set is a lot faster than in a list, but for anything else it would rather be slightly slower.

Comment: This will be used in quite a few places, I was hoping to return HashSet<Poster> from the data-layer to be used by many other methods, just looking for the most efficient method on average.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, if you implement a `IEqualityComparer<Poster>`, you need to implement these methods. You will need to pass the equality comparer to the `HashSet<Poster>` constructor.

Another option is to implement the equality/hashcode logic in the `Poster` class itself; in this case you must override these methods:

```
public bool Equals(object obj)
public int GetHashCode()
```