# How are .NET compilers able to construct O(1) lookups for any T in a HashSet<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I don't understand how a compiler can be smart enough to construct an O(1) lookup for `MyObject` where I can put **anything** inside

```
public class MyObject
{
    // ... 
}
```

I understand how this can be done for a limited number of non-primitives such as

```
public class MyObject
{
    int i { get; set; }
    char c { get; set; }
}
```

but how can it possibly know how to do this for any implementation of `MyObject`?

Comment: It is done by turning an object into a number.  Which then serves as its index in the collection.  Google "hash function" and read your favorite C# language book about Object.GetHashCode().

Comment: I don't think this is close enough to mark it as a duplicate but I go in to a in depth explination in to how Dictionary (and HashSet) use hash codes to get O(1) lookups [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28593764/gethashcode-method-with-dictionary-and-hashset/28593852#28593852)

Comment: Protip: If you create a `struct` all of this is done for free :D

Comment: No you don't understand how it can be done for a limited number of  non-primitives.  You will get 0(1) lookup with your MyObject.  The problem is the two MyObject with identical i can c will not be equal.  They will be two entries in the HashSet.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Get the hash-code
2. Modulo that down to produce an index into an array.
3. Look there. If an item is present see if it is equal.

So far, perfectly O(1). It falls down if a lot of items end up having hash-codes that modulo-down to the same index. This happening a bit is expected and dealt with, but if it happens all the time you end up with O(n) behaviour (and with really bad constant costs).

All objects by default have a `GetHashCode()` and an `Equals()` based on reference identity (that is, they are only equal to themselves). Overriding those changes the concept of equality it has, and hence you must always change `GetHashCode()` when you change `Equals()` (all objects that are equal must have equal hash codes). You can also enforce the use of a different concept of equality by using an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation which provides a different `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` to use.

Answer (score 6):

Each object has a [Hash Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function) associated with it. There is a method [`GetHashCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx) *(defined as virtual in the base `object` class)* that has to be overridden in the class so that `HashSet` can work properly.

> A **hash code is a numeric value** that is used to insert and identify
>   an object in a hash-based collection such as the
>   Dictionary class, the Hashtable class, or a type derived
>   from the DictionaryBase class. The GetHashCode method provides this
>   hash code for algorithms that need quick checks of object equality.

With your current class, it will not work properly *(since `GetHashCode` is not overridden)*. The comparison for equality will be done on the basis of reference instead of actual values.

Comment: It will work with their class, just with the default identity-based sort of equality.

Comment: Ah, ok. The "has to be overridden" is what I didn't know. I assumed that everything that inherits from `object` has a formula already, that there was some formula generic enough to work on anything that extends `object`

Comment: @JonHanna, yes it will be based on reference equality, and not the actual values.