# Check key / value pair in List

Tags: c#, list, keyvaluepair

I have list declared as

```
 List<KeyValuePair<string, Int64>> KPList = new List<KeyValuePair<string, long>>();
```

I need to check if a combination of key and value already exists. I can't use dictionary since I need to have unique combination of key and value where in case a key will have multiple values but as a single pair

```
if(!KPList.Any(p=> p.Key ==keyp && p.Value == valuep))
```

What is wrong in this?

Comment: What makes you think something's wrong? You could use `Tuple<string,long>` instead of `KeyValuePair` if you're on at least .Net 3.5 (iirc), but otherwise, seems fine - assuming you're OK with O(n) lookup.

Comment: Yes, your code is ok ! What error does it give ? Can you provide sample values and expected output ?

Comment: The only problem could be mismatched spaces around `==` :) . Not really sure what are you looking for...

Comment: Thank you Blorgbeard. Whether Tuple<string,long> as dictionary key will allow adding unique combination of string,long as key?

Comment: It is allowing duplicate combination of key value pair

Answer (score 4):

You can also use *HashSet*, which doesn't have values, but works as you need.

```
HashSet< Tuple<string, long> > KPSet = new HashSet< Tuple<string, long> >(); 
...
if(KPSet.Contains(p))
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Here 'p' is a unique combination of key and value or it works only on unique key

Comment: In this case the key is the combination of string and Int64. So pairs {64, "abc"}, {64, "def"}, {22, "abc"} will be considered different.

Comment: It should be actually otherwise :-) {"abc",64}, {"abc","22"},{"xyz",64},{"xyz",22} - Is that ok?

Comment: Yes, they all are different keys.

Comment: It is allowing duplication combination {"abc",64}, {"abc",64} :(

Comment: What do you mean it is? If you add two identical keys, only one instance will be kept in the set.

Comment: if(!KpSet.Contains(p)) - condition is true in case {"abc",64} already exists and I try to add the same

Comment: KeyValuePair<K,V>.GetHashCode() returns the hash code of the key. This approach will not work at all. You would need a version of KeyValuePair that combines its key and value for hashing and comparison.

Comment: That said, HashSet IS what you want, you just need a different class/struct for the elements.

Comment: I just did test it. Changes to Value have no effect on GetHashCode() for me.

Comment: @glenebob Now, test using HashSet. Again, it does work with KeyValuePair.

Comment: Ah right, it does work, because apparently comparison is effected by changes to Value, while hash value is not. That defeats the purpose of the hash table; depending on Key variability, it could be less efficient than a List<>.

Comment: Please suggest me, what should I use now?

Comment: @JameerBasha my examples works fine. You could try to change *KeyValuePair* to *Tuple* to get some performance efficiency. However, both ways are technically correct.

Comment: @glenebob http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality
As answered in the question, HashSet compares using **both** GetHashCode() **and** key.Equals().

Comment: Tuple<> does appear to use all values in its hash function, so it will work as designed in a HashSet. @user3290260, using a hash table for items that do not produce reasonable hash codes is simply poor design.

Comment: @user3290260, if you update your answer to use Tuple, with a comment about correct hashing vs KeyValuePair, I'll remove my down-vote.

Answer (score 1):

For easy-use and best performance I would like to suggest use combination of Dictionary and HashSet :

```
var KPDict = new Dictionary<string, HashSet<long>>();
```

Then it will provides you O(1)+O(1) lookup complexity and easy check of value:

```
if (KPDict.ContainsKey(keyp) && KPDict[keyp].Contains(valuep)) {
    //do some actions
}
else{
    //some logic in case keyp, valuep pair not found in KPDict
}
```

Comment: dictionary has no sort, data can not be inserted at specific index etc - bad solution

Comment: @PernerOl bad solution for what?

Comment: The user was asking for a possibility to check the Key/values in a list with key value pair.
As already mentioned, a dictionary is no appropriate alternative for a list, because it misses several things like sort (you would need foreach loops, or lambdas), or inserting at at specific index. as you don't know, what else the list will be used for, it's illogic to say 'use a dictionary instead' - the user will have his reasons he chose a list and not a dictionary. if he would like to know, what kind of datatype performs best, he probably would have asked for it, don't you think? ;)

Comment: @PernerOl From the question, "I can't use dictionary since I need to have unique combination of key and value ..", which suggests that the OP has no issue with using a `Dictionary`, other than that it wouldn't allow multiple values with the same key. You are assuming a lot of things in your comments that you can't know.