# How to use HashSet<T> with objects to filter unique objects

Tags: c#

As `HashSet<T>` provides unique items post filtering it. I wanted to use this with some given class objects but it didn't work however it is working with primitive types like int. My classes are now implementing IEqualityComparer.GetHashCode method is important here.

```
        class Address : IEqualityComparer<Address>
            {
                public int PinCode { get; set; }
                public string LocalAddress { get; set; }

                public bool Equals(Address x, Address y)
                {
                    if (x is null && y is null)
                        return true;
                    else if (x is null || y is null)
                        return false;
                    else if ((x.PinCode == y.PinCode) && (x.LocalAddress == y.LocalAddress))
                        return true;
                    else
                        return false;
                }

                public int GetHashCode(Address obj) =>
                   obj.LocalAddress.GetHashCode() * 17 + obj.PinCode.GetHashCode();

            }

    class Person : IEqualityComparer<Person>
        {
            public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
            {
                if (x is null && y is null)
                    return true;
                else if (x is null || y is null)
                    return false;
                else if ((x.Name == y.Name) && (x.Address.LocalAddress == y.Address.LocalAddress) && (x.Address.PinCode == y.Address.PinCode))
                    return true;
                else
                    return false;
            }

            public int GetHashCode(Person obj) =>
                obj.Name.GetHashCode() * 17 + obj.Address.PinCode.GetHashCode() + obj.Address.LocalAddress.GetHashCode();

            public string Name { get; set; }
            public Address Address { get; set; }
        }

class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<Person> people = new List<Person>()
                {
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Amar",
                        Address=new Address
                        {
                            PinCode=500018,
                            LocalAddress="Hyderabad"
                        }
                    },
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Amar",
                        Address=new Address
                        {
                            PinCode=500018,
                            LocalAddress="Hyderabad"
                        }
                    },
                    new Person
                    {
                        Name="Alok",
                        Address=new Address
                        {
                            PinCode=500018,
                            LocalAddress="Hyderabad"
                        }
                    }
                };

            HashSet<Person> uniquePeople = new HashSet<Person>(new Person());
            uniquePeople.UnionWith(people);

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Actual Result :- Count of this is coming as 2
Expected Result :- Count should be 2 
        }

Comment: Because you are using a custom class, you have to implement `IEquatable` to tell if two items are the same

Comment: Hi, per your comment I have modified code as

Comment: If you don't use a custom comparer as explained in the duplicate, you also need to override GetHashCode(). See the [second duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8952003/how-does-hashset-compare-elements-for-equality/15413983).

Comment: as explained to duplicate(and i made a mistake in the name) you should override `IEqualityComparer` and then  do `var uniquePeople = new HashSet<Person>(new Person());
            uniquePeople.UnionWith(people);`

Comment: Thanks for your input @styx

Comment: Thanks @codeCaster. Post investing 1 day in GetHashCode, My codes are working fine now