# Why is GetHashCode not called during Contains?

Tags: c#, hashset, hashcode

Until today my understanding was that a `HashSet` uses `GetHashCode` inside `Contains`. That is also said e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8952026/5333340).

I wrote a little `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string? a, string? b)
    {
        return a == b;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string a)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And used it like so:

```
public void TestMyComparer()
{
    var x = new HashSet<string>(new []{ "hello", "world" });
    bool helloInside = x.Contains("hello", new MyComparer());
}
```

But `TestMyComparer` does not throw a `NotImplementedException`, as I expected. Instead, it returns `true`.

**Why?**

Comment: There's no overload of `HashSet<T>.Contains` which takes a `IComparer<T>`. So your code won't compile.

Comment: Fixing your code so the `MyComparer` is passed to the `HashSet<T>` constructor **does** lead to the `NotImplementedException` being thrown: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7uvoFt

Comment: @canton7 My code **does** compile. There is `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.Contains<T>` extension method.

Comment: Aah, `Enumerable.Contains`. Right. That's just going through each element one-by-one looking for a match: the fact that you're iterating over a `HashSet<T>`  is irrelevant. Since it's just checking each element for equality in turn, there's no point in it using the hash codes. [This is the implementation](https://source.dot.net/#System.Linq/System/Linq/Contains.cs,33)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use your custom comparer in `HashSet.Contains`, pass it to the [the constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1.-ctor?view=net-6.0#system-collections-generic-hashset-1-ctor(system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))).

```
var x = new HashSet<string>(new MyComparer());
x.Add("hello");
x.Add("world");
bool helloInside = x.Contains("hello");
```

Now `GetHashCode` [is used](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Core/System/Collections/Generic/HashSet.cs,06d905a0ac76e4f5) since you use a set based collection and not [`Enumerable.Contains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.contains?view=net-6.0#system-linq-enumerable-contains-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-0-system-collections-generic-iequalitycomparer((-0)))) which just enumerates all items and compares them with `Equals`.